# how can i get the userId or membershipId of the user that log in in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a Employer-worker website. My problem is whenever a specific employer is log in I want to filter all the position that certain employer have and put it in a dropdown. How can I get the `userId` of the current user for me be able to filter the position.

In the database of the employer I have a field named `userId` it a FK of the `userId` in my `membershipId` table.

I found this on the net:

```
Guid userGuid = (Guid)Membership.GetUser().ProviderUserKey;
```

But I can't understand how can I use or put this on my controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
//simplified version
MembershipUser membershipUser = Membership.GetUser();
string UserID = membershipUser.ProviderUserKey.ToString();
```

The way you found is also correct, but the questions in where you want to use this in controller.

Most common uses are like redirecting the users to the corresponding view, which is accessible to the current user.

Comment: sir where i should put that codes.. in the employer controller or in the accountController?.. thanks sir

Comment: Use account controller, this is never fixed, you can do it according to your requirements or choose the best which serves the purpose

Comment: what do you mean that it was never fixed? i can use it  too in the employer controller>?

Comment: Do You always use the default controllers given by mvc for making your application???...

Comment: that's why, a user can have a anonymous controller which can take care of the activities like checking the user id, redirecting to the corresponding view etc. :)

Comment: suddenly ive got errors on my database.. but when i put a break point to your given point.. it point out that is already fetch the right id.. tnx a lot..still gonna try it to compare... thank you again sir

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
User.Identity.Name
```

inside your controller